# how to adjust the position of a tooltip

Tags: css, angular, tooltip

I'm developing a chat app using angular 6

what i want to do is displaying a tooltip when hover over group member when creating a group.
The problem is when setting the tooltip style to left: 1% the first member tooltip is perfect but it's effect the last member in the list as half of the tooltip is not shown.

what i want is to set the first member css to left: 1%

[image: the tooltip is placed to the left]

and the last member to right: 20%; 
[image: the tooltip is placed to the right]

selectedMemberComponent.html

```
 <div class="selectedMember">
 <img [src]="selectedMember.Image">
 <span class="full-name">{{selectedMember.Name}}</span>
</div>
```

selectedMemberComponent.css

```
  .selected-member .full-name {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #d73272;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;

  }



  .selected-member:hover .full-name {
    visibility: visible;


  }

   .selected-member span:first-child{
    left: 1%;
  }

  .selected-member span:last-child{
    right: 20%;
  }
```

Comment: can you please provide a working fiddle for the same. It will be helpful in understanding your problem better.

Comment: i attached screenshots , please check again

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like,

```css
.selectedMember {
  position: relative;
}

.selectedMemberImg {
  width: 50pt;
}

.full-name {
  display: none;
  color: black;
}

.selectedMemberImg:hover+.full-name {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
}

.selectedMember:last-child .selectedMemberImg:hover+.full-name {  
  left: 40%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="selectedMember">
    <img class="selectedMemberImg" src="http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg">
    <span class="full-name">Monalisa</span>
  </div>

  <div class="selectedMember">
    <img class="selectedMemberImg" src="http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg">
    <span class="full-name">Monalisa</span>
  </div>

  <div class="selectedMember">
    <img class="selectedMemberImg" src="http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg">
    <span class="full-name">Monalisa</span>
  </div>

  <div class="selectedMember">
    <img class="selectedMemberImg" src="http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg">
    <span class="full-name">Monalisa</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please explain what's going on ?

Comment: I have shown to you how to style your last element. I have made all file-name position absolute, you can position it using top, right, bottom and left according to your need.